# Loops in loops and increment staying at 0 in C++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, increment

I have 2 while loops in a while loop like so in the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int p = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    int p3 = 0;
    while(p < 10)
    {
        while(p2 < 10)
        {
            while(p3 < 10)
            {
                cout << p << endl;
                cout << p2 << endl;
                cout << p3 << endl;
                cout << endl << endl;
                p3++;
            }
            p2++;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

Could somebody please explain to me why is the output:

```
0
0
0


0
0
1


0
0
2


0
0
3


0
0
4


0
0
5


0
0
6


0
0
7


0
0
8


0
0
9
```

It's like the p++ and the p2++ are not working and there is just one loop of the p3 one. This is simplified code of what I have in my project and the result of it is exactly the problem I have with it. What I was expecting to happen is that p3 would keep going from 0 to 9 for each p2 going 0 to 9 and for every p going 0 through 9. So the result should get to p=9, p2=9, p3=9 eventually. I have been starring at it for a while now and just don't get it. Looks simple enough and should be kicking but its not...

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Oh gosh. Have you even tried to think about the logic of the code?

Comment: Do you realize that you are not resetting the `p2` and `p3` variables once their loop finishes executing?

Comment: omg just realized whats wrong. Sorry guys I guess im just super tired and not thinking straight anymore. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: While this question might be simple, it's not *that* bad for a beginner question. He's posted the full code, the actual output, and his expected output. Because of that, +1 from me. As far as beginner questions go, it's pretty decent (even if it is a simple logic error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time `p3` equals 10, it will never re-enter the `while (p3 < 10)` loop (because once you've incremented it to 10, it will never be less than 10 and will never re-enter that loop). So yes, `p` and `p2` do increment, but they never get printed because `p3 == 10` at that point in time.

Answer (score 0):

After p3 gets to 10, the condition in the inner loop is never satisfied again; the same holds also for p2.

Answer (score 0):

**You are not resetting your iterators at the beginning of each inner loop:**

```
{
  int p = 0;
  int p2 = 0;
  int p3 = 0;
  while (p < 10) {
    // p2 NOT reset here! - just move "int p2 = 0;" here.
    while (p2 < 10) {
      // p3 NOT reset here! - just move "int p3 = 0;" here.
      while (p3 < 10) {
        // ...
        p3++;
      }
      p2++;
    }
    p++;
  }
}
```